# Can't set font styles on AdvancedBandedGridView

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

Is it at all possible to set font properties; height, family and style in DevExpress views?
I use the following code to set the specified properties:

```
advBandedGridView1.Appearance.BandPanel.Font.Bold = FontStyle.Bold;
advBandedGridView1.Appearance.BandPanel.Font.Height = 12;
```

But I get the following error:
"Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Font.Height' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Is there a work-around that I should be aware of?
I construct and populate my view in the code, at runtime. 
So a solution along those lines is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BandPanel` is a read only property. This property can be overridden by individual bands. Use the `band's GridBand.AppearanceHeader` property for this purpose.

For more details you may want to check the following  : http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBandedGridBandedViewAppearances_BandPaneltopic